# Distribution of first $9$ natural numbers

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The question states

> The first $9$ natural numbers are to be divided in three groups $g_1$, $g_2$ and $g_3$ of equal size. In how many different ways can this be done if the sum of numbers in each group is odd?"

What I thought was to split it into cases. The three numbers chosen for one group should be of the following types:(for the sum to to be odd)

1. $2$ even $1$ odd $\to$ $\binom{4}{2}$ $\binom{5}{1}$
2. All $3$ odd $\to$ $\binom{5}{3}$

Summing this gives $40$ and I proceeded to choose for the next group by considering  that case $1$ had occurred (for selection of first group) and with that new sample space tried forming the same cases. Similarly assuming that case $2$ has occurred I tried making cases for selection of group $2$. But this just lead to a lot of chaos. The given answer is $360$. How do I approach this question?

Comment: I completely agree with N.F.Taussig's answer.  Further, although the analysis in his answer is sophisticated, I (for one) don't see any way to simplify the analysis.  I advise you to examine the problem's **background.**  That is, is this problem from a contest, book, or class?  If the problem is from a book or class, then what theorems or previously solved problems led up to this problem?  That is, how did your teacher or book *intend* that you solve the problem?  ...see next comment

Comment: If you accept that N.F.Taussig's answer (or some similar analysis) was *intended*, the next question is: has the problem's **background** (re my previous comment) given you the training that would make it feasible for you to originate N.F.Taussig's answer?  If you feel that the answer is **no,** then I advise re-examining the problem's background, and then consulting your teacher, **on this key issue.**

Comment: This question was given after we were taught how to distribute m+n distict things into 2 groups of size m,n without restrictions. I was able to follow the answer provided so I guess thr tools were provided but I had trouble  in applying them.

Comment: Interesting.  It is for **you** to decide whether you will benefit by broaching this issue with your teacher.  Personally, I regard the fact that you can follow N.F.Taussig's answer as **inconclusive.**  Sometimes, the teacher/book will confront the student with a problem without first providing adequate training.  It is not a good idea to assume that your teacher/book is blameless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first nine natural numbers contain exactly five odd numbers.  Each group must contain an odd number of natural numbers if the sum of the numbers in each group is to be odd.  The only way to do this is to have one group with three odd numbers and two groups with exactly one odd number.

Choose which three odd numbers are placed in the group with three odd numbers, which can be done in $\binom{5}{3}$ ways.  Choose which two of the four even numbers will be placed in the group with the smaller of the two remaining odd numbers, which can be done in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways.  The other two even numbers must be placed in the group with the remaining odd number.  Hence, there are $$\binom{5}{3}\binom{4}{2}$$ unlabeled groups of three natural numbers, each having an odd sum, which can be formed from the first nine natural numbers.  Since the groups are labeled, there are $$\binom{5}{3}\binom{4}{2}3!$$ labeled groups of three natural numbers, each of which has an odd sum, which can be formed from the first nine natural numbers.